# C++ GDB breakpoint for member functions

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints, member-functions

I am having trouble with using GDB on my c++ program. I want to set up a break point for my class member function and I'm not sure on the syntax of how to do it. My program is working find right now and I'm just trying to learn to use GDB. My problem is all the information I find on line only really deals with just a main() file and no other functions or classes and if they involve classes its only using a function with a void return statement.

I have a binary search tree class. I want to set a break point at a function in my program.
here's the section of my header file.

```
class BST
{
    BST()
    ...
    private:
    int add((BST * root, BST *src);
}
```

I am telneting into a command line linux server for school.
I can get GDB running with my program just fine with g++ -g *.cpp (there are other files that are working fine) and the file is saved as a.out.
I run GDB with

```
gdb ./a.out
```

and I get into GDB. I can get a break point for the void display function just fine with

```
b BST::disp_block()
```

but how do I do it with the add function I have tried

```
b BST::int add(BST*, BST *)
b int BST::add(BST*, BST *)
b BST::add(BST*, BST *)
```

and I even tried with the argument names

```
b BST::int add(BST * root, BST * src)
b int BST::add(BST * root, BST * src)
b BST::add(BST * root, BST * src)
```

and I keep getting the error

```
Function "____" not defined.
Make break point pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

How do I set up a break point for a member function like this one? Im assuming watch points would be the same format, if not could you explain that too.

Comment: In the absence of overloads or if you want to break in all overloads, `b BST::add`. No need for arguments. Note that you need to include the namespace also if your class is in a namespace.

Comment: It is also possible to set a breakpoint in gdb via filename:linenumber.  If your function is in bst.c, on line 25, the command would be:
(gdb) b bst.c:25

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Dark Falcon said, `break BST::add` should work if you don't have overloads.

You can also type:

```
(gdb) break 'BST::add(<TAB>
```

(note the single quote). This should prompt GDB to perform tab-completion, and finish the line like so:

```
(gdb) break 'BST::add(BST*, BST*)
```

and which point you can add the terminating `'`' and hit Enter to add the breakpoint.

> I can get a break point for the void display function

Function return type is not part of its signature and has *nothing* to do with what's happening.

Comment: Another trick worth knowing is to use `info func` with a regexp argument to find what gdb thinks a function might be named.

Comment: Note the symbol has to be *fully* namespace-qualified before tab-completion will work.

Answer (score 9):

You may need to specify the namespace if any defined for the class. If it other than the standard namespace std. The file name is optional, if you are executing the correct binary. You can verify if the symbol exists on the executable via. "nm -C" command, where -C handles name mangling for C++.

So to summarise with an Example: If the namespace is "mySpace" and the class is "X" whose member is "Y", then the breakpoint should be like the one below, "(gdb) b mySpace::X::Y"